# Python pass result of a mysql query as a class

Tags: python, database, string, class, dynamic

I'm not a python expert but came across with some weird idea that I don't know if it's possible in some way.

I have a table with some users like this:

```
|user | language|
|1    |    es   |
|2    |    en   |
```

I have 2 classes with several strings ie

```
 class en():
    h ="hello"
    a ="goodbye"
    
    class es():
    h = "hola"
    a = "adios"
```

I also have a query that returns en or es for specific user

```
flang = q.idioma(uid).replace("'","")// this returns as es or en
```

What I want to achieve is ... to call:

flang.h but print the string dynamically

For example if user 1 gets flang.h he should see "hola" as well as with flang.a "adios" and same thing for user 2 but with strings in English.

Nevertheless even when flang gets printed as en or es it doesn't get recognized as the class is there a way to do that? Or could I store all the strings in a database and call them with some weird query?

As I have said I'm learning Python by myself so I don't know if it's even possible

Answer (score 0):

By assuming this line `q.idioma(uid).replace("'","")` will return a `string`.

You can try to put it into dictionary like this

```
class en():
    h ="hello"
    a ="goodbye"
    
class es():
    h = "hola"
    a = "adios"

languages = {"en": en, "es": es}

flang = languages.get(q.idioma(uid).replace("'",""))
```